# Powerpoint 365 Interop C# - Setting Picture Transparency

Tags: c#, image, powerpoint, interop, transparency

I'm using Powerpoint 365 and C# Interop in VS2022 to add a picture to a Powerpoint presentation using:

```
 var pic = slide.Shapes.AddPicture(FileName: pictureName, LinkToFile: MsoTriState.msoFalse, SaveWithDocument: MsoTriState.msoCTrue, Left: picLeft, Top: picTop, Width: picWidth, Height: picHeight);
```

Once the picture is added, I can go into Powerpoint and right-click the image, select Picture Format then Picture Transparency to set image transparency. I've searched, but cannot find how to set that transparency directly in C#.
Tried

```
pic.Fill.Transparency = 0.5f;
```

but that didn't work. How could I do this in the interop. Thanks.